# API post call via kubernetes ingress is never end even if the task complete , but when the API call targeting specific container the job call ended

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I have 2 Kubernetes pods (AKS) running rest API dotnet core application, hosted by Dotnet kestrel, the interaction with the pods being made via ingress.

1. if I'm making the API call via ingress and the job that is being made is longer the 10 min, the call will never end.
2. if I'm targeting the pod IP directly (bypass the ingress), the job will end, no matter how much time it takes for it to be completed.
3. could it be related to kestrel working behind a reverse proxy?

here I include the Dockerfile

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0.400-focal-amd64
EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY ./ODS_Deployment/* ./
RUN groupadd --gid 1001 nonroot \
&& useradd --gid nonroot --create-home --uid 1001 nonroot \
&& chown -R nonroot:nonroot /workspace \
&& chmod u+x ./SomeoneElses.dist.Service.API
USER nonroot
CMD ["./StasK.dist.Service.API","--urls","http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

here I included all the deployment including the ingress configuration

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: K8S_APP_NAME
  namespace: K8S_APP_NAME
  labels:
    app: K8S_APP_NAME
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: K8S_APP_NAME
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: K8S_APP_NAME
        application: ods
        enviorment: K8S_APP_ENVIORMENT
        location: K8S_APP_LOCATION
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: K8S_APP_NAME
          image: ACR_IMG_URL
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1024Mi"
              cpu: "256m"
            limits:
              memory: "2048Mi"
              cpu: "512m"
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: K8S_IMG_SECRET
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            - weight: 100
              podAffinityTerm:
                labelSelector:
                  matchExpressions:
                    - key: app
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - web
                topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: K8S_APP_NAME
  namespace: K8S_APP_NAME
spec:
  selector:
    app: K8S_APP_NAME
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: K8S_APP_NAME-ingress
  namespace: K8S_APP_NAME
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTP"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "session-cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "7200"
    nginx.org/hsts: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "APP_URL_1"
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: K8S_APP_NAME
            port:
              number: 5000
```

Comment: Did the solution of Harsh Manvar help you?

Comment: no, didn't help, I suspect that the kestrel is the cause of the issue, but I am not sure, one more thing this project was published in windows server VM  like this `dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained true -r linux-x64`

Answer (score 0):

> if I'm making the API call via ingress and the job that is being made
> is longer the 20 min, the call will never end.

For howmuch long time you checked this?

Your ingress proxy read timeout is set to 7200 seconds which means nearly 2 hours.

> if I'm targeting the pod IP directly, the job will end, no matter how
> much time it takes for it to be completed.

ideally, you should be using the **service name** for internal communication, this might be due to the application closing the request not handling connection for long time, or depends on the configuration of the app also.

You can also check more at : https://reads.kubric.io/blog/dns-lookup-timeouts-in-kubernetes/